# Cannot put datepicker into form

Tags: php, drupal

I have created a module in Drupal 8 that creates a block with its respective form, everything works fine, but I can not put a datepicker field, I have tried several things but they do not work.

```
 $form['date'] = [
     '#type' => 'date_range',
     '#title' => $this->t('Date'),
     '#date_date_format' => $date_format,
     '#date_time_format' => $time_format,
     '#description' => date($date_format, time()),
     '#default_value' => DrupalDateTime::createFromTimestamp(time()),
 ];
```